# Инжекция dll в explorer.exe

Tags: c++, winapi, code-injection

Нужно заинжектиться в explorer.exe, имею `dll` который имеет такой код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "windows.h"

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Hello injected to explorer.exe", "Info", MB_OK);
}
```

Я пробовал собирать как 32 битку так и 64 битку. Windows 10 x64.

Есть инжектор с таким кодом:

```
char *CDP = TEXT("C:\\ProgramData\\windows.dll");
    printf("Hi from inject\n");
    HANDLE proc_handle;
    printf("Hi from inject\n");
    LPVOID RemoteString;
    printf("Hi from inject\n");
    LPVOID LoadLibAddy;
    printf("Hi from inject\n");
    if (pID == 0)
    {
        printf("pID not found\n");
        return false;
    }
    proc_handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, pID);
    printf("Hi from inject\n");
    if (proc_handle == 0) {
        printf("Cannot take file handle\n");
        return false;
    }
    LoadLibAddy = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
    printf("Hi from inject\n");
    RemoteString = (LPVOID)VirtualAllocEx(proc_handle, NULL, strlen(CDP), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    printf("Hi from inject\n");
    WriteProcessMemory(proc_handle, RemoteString, CDP, strlen(CDP), NULL);
    printf("Hi from inject\n");
    CreateRemoteThread(proc_handle, NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibAddy, RemoteString, NULL, NULL);
    printf("Injection was successful\n");
    CloseHandle(proc_handle);
    return true;
```

`printf("Hi from inject\n")` используется для отладки. Также собирал как 32 так и 64 битку. Только ничего не инжектится. В программы типа торрентов или браузеров инжектится без проблем. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вроде такой метод основан на том, что kernel32.dll всегда по одному адресу загружается. Не может ли в explorer.exe стоять защита от такого безобразия - или какой-нибудь ASLR включён по умолчанию для него?

Comment: Ну насколько я читал, то защиты там никакой нету, а если и есть где это можно увидеть/отследить?

Comment: В Process Explorer ([бложик](https://blog.didierstevens.com/2011/01/18/quickpost-checking-aslr/) на англ.): выбрать процесс, ткнуть "показать DLL", в нижней панельке правым кликом выбрать столбцы, поставить галку возле ASLR. В списке DLL можно дважды ткнуть на kernel32.dll, будет показан адрес загрузки. Интереса ради пощёлкал - в основном один и тот же адрес, но изредка отличается.

Comment: Это все конечно хорошо, но есть же хоть какая-нибудь возможность зaгрузки моего dll в память explorer.exe?

Comment: Зачем пользоваться хаком, когда есть официальный способ загрузки пользовательских расширений именно  для explorer-а? http://rsdn.org/article/winshell/shlext1.xml

Comment: Ошибок не выдает. Инжектится только вот MessageBox не запускается

Comment: `char *CDP = TEXT("C:\\ProgramData\\windows.dll");` - в чем цель такого бессмысленного применения макро `TEXT`???

Answer (score 1):

> Я пробовал собирать как 32 битку так и 64 битку. Windows 10 x64.

Вам нужен именно x64, т.к в данном методе нужно, чтобы инжектор, длл, и целевой процесс были оба одной разрядности.

Поэтому проверьте, что вы пробовали собирать и **инжектор, и dll** как x64

Ну и мелочи:

```
RemoteString = (LPVOID)VirtualAllocEx(proc_handle, NULL, strlen(CDP), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

WriteProcessMemory(proc_handle, RemoteString, CDP, strlen(CDP), NULL);
```

У вас указан CDP = TEXT(...), в том случае если это будет юникод, то запишется ровно половина строки, т.к 1 символ = 2 байта, в юникоде, а вы выделяет по количеству символов. В данном случае советую сделать что-либо более конкретное убрав TEXT и указав тип CHAR*

```
    printf("Hi from inject\n");
```

Ну и данный код не имеет смысла, т.к при ошибке выполнение не прерывается, а продолжается.

И проверьте по поводу LoadLibraryA, в том случае если передаете юникод - LoadLibraryA вернет ошибку уже внутри целевого процесса.

Т.к следующая запись:

```
CHAR* a =TEXT(...)
```

во все не гарантирует, что CHAR будет указывать на ANSI строку, а не на UNICODE, если в настройках компилятора стоит предпочитание юникода, то в данный указатель запишется адрес совсем не на то, что ожидается.